# How to enable/Disable Forms Authentication in IIS

Tags: iis, wix, appcmd

I am building a setup package using the WIX tool. I have a requirement for enabling/disabling Forms Authentication for a particular virtual directory in IIS based on the user requirement. I have tried appcmd command but could not get it to work:

`appcmd set config "Default Web Site/Test" /commit:WEBROOT /section:system.web/authentication /mode:Forms /commit:apphost`

Please suggest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that worked for me..

To Enable Forms Authentication:

```
appcmd set config "Default Web Site/Test" /section:system.web/authentication /mode:Forms
```

To Disable Forms Authentication:

```
appcmd set config "Default Web Site/Test" /section:system.web/authentication /mode:Windows
```

Just removed `/commit:WEBROOT` to get it work.

If I am Adding `/commit:WEBROOT` the above code will work only for "Default Web Site" and not for "Default Web Site/Test"